# Possible to kind of subclass a layout view in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, layout, ruby-on-rails-3.2, erb

I have a great default layout view in `/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`. Now I have a bunch of instructional web pages to display. Easy enough.. I just route them to a controller and have the individual pages' `.html.erb` files in the `views` directory. But they all share common html/css features around the core instructional content.

So I'd love for them to all have a nice layout called something like `layouts/instructional.html.erb` and that layout simply extends the `application.html.erb` layout. Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible to use nested layout, from your module layout you can have custom code and extend the main layout.

Have a look at the example her : http://m.onkey.org/nested-layouts-in-rails-3